# 2-sided plane: bottom image flipped?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, shaders, uv-image-editor

I created a 2-sided plane with an image on each side but the bottom image is flipped.

[image][image]

I saw on another forum that the mirroring the second set of uvs could fix this but I'm new to using uvs in Blender and I'm not really sure what they mean by this. I only see one set of uvs when I went to the uv editor. How would you flip the uvs on the second set?

Blend file (with answer's 1st method fix): [image]

Comment: links in pasteall.org expire after a few months, please consider using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or other permanent hosts for your files. The idea is that other users who run into similar issues can learn from your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities (at least) :

**Modifying the scale in the texture panel**

Setting the texture (of color2) X scale to -1 will flip the image horizontally.

[image]

**Adding a vector mapping node**

The same principle, but set up in the material nodes :

[image]

**Adding a second UV map**

- Create a second UV map in the properties panel using the '+' button (1) and eventually rename it
- Unwrap in that new UV map and scale it -1 along X using <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>-1</kbd> (in 2)
- Add UV map nodes in the material (3)

[image]